# Dialogflow Slack Cards

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, slack

I have a bit of a silly question about the Slack integration of Dialogflow.

When I use a card to the response in Slack, the buttons work perfectly. But they don't type the title nor the postback of the button to the chat. The Botframework from Microsoft works like this and I think it's easier for the user to see what he answered if he scroll up the conversation history.

My question is, is this how it is, or can I change this behavior so that on clicking a card button the text of the button is typed in the chat?

For the moment, I'm only using code to execute functions when needed.

This is the "card" I'm talking about:

[image: This is the "card" I'm talking about]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly change the behavior of the card as this is internal to Slack and/or Dialogflow. There is however a workaround: If you are using a Webhook for fulfillment you can send multiple responses messages back and thus simply include the button text before the actual card. The button text will then only show up after the request is fulfilled (not immediately after the user tapped it), but that seems about the best you can get.